# Recreating SBS IIS virtual directories

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I'm having to recreate SBS OWA Virtual Directories because the exchange install failed during initial install and had to be installed manually. All is well and good so far except, I'm unable to create OAB and WebServices Virtual Directories. My error is the same for both:

New-WebServicesVirtualDirectory : An error occurred while creating the IIS virtual directory 'IIS://EXCHSVR.domain.local/W3SVC/3/ROOT/EWS' on 'EXCHSVR'. At line:1 char:32

I can create both of these Virtual Directories within the Default Web Site with no problem, only when I try to create them in the SBS Web App site does it give these errors

Autodiscover virtual directory has same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, there were some corrupt Virtual Directories in the metabase that were not being overwritten. I used Metabase Explorer and checked the SBS Web App and removed the entries then they were able to be created.